# Personalizar link css conforme a url

Tags: css

Já vi em algum lugar que tem como aplicar um determinado css a um "**a**" caso tenha um determinado texto no link, porém não consigo mais encontrar.

Por exemplo, tenho os seguintes links em meu html

```
<a href="http://site.com.br/nothing">Link para nada</a>
<a href="http://site.com.br/something"><Link para alguma coisa</a>
<a href="http://other.com.br/something"><Link para alguma coisa</a>
```

Supondo que queira que somente o link que tenha **something** no `href` tenha um estilo diferente, como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: @devgaspa As duas respostas estão corretas, mas aceitei a do Alan pois foi a primeira postada.

Comment: @AlanRezende Não tinha escrito claramente o que precisava, editei a pergunta adicionando mais um link. O que preciso é considerar apenas uma parte desse link (something). Usando a resposta de vocês encontrei já como fazer, no css é só usar o "*" logo após o href - a[href*="something"].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

utilize por exemplo

```
a[href="http://site.com.br/something"]{
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Para considerar apenas uma parte da url, basta usar um * logo após o href

```
a[href*="something"]{
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-links-depending-on-destination/ Documentação completa com referência de links externos, internos e absolutos.

Answer (score 3):

Usando este seletor.

```
a[href="http://site.com.br/nothing"] {
  color: red;
}
```

[Referência](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/).